# Entity Framework not using my connection string when using the Authorize attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Everything works fine on my development machine but when I deploy to my production environment the controller I have protected with an AuthorizeAttribute doesn't use my connection string

The error I get when executing code from that controller (after I log in to authorize) contains:

```
The connection string specifies a local Sql Server Express instance using a database location within the application's App_Data directory
```

I'm not using a local SQL server express and the other functionality not protected by the authorize attribute works just fine hitting the correct database.  I only have one connection string and I know its defined correctly.  Removing the authorize attribute allows the controller to work just fine hitting the correct database (both in my development and production environments) so I'm pretty sure its related to the attribute.  I just can't see how this would be coming in to play.

Authorize declaration:

```
 [Authorize(Roles="Admins")]
public class AdminController : Controller 
. . .
```

Connection String in the Production Environment:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=11.11.111.1111,1533;Initial Catalog=Blah;User ID=WTRDb;Password=FooBar" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Context Constructor:

```
public EFDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
{
. . .
```

This is using EF6 in an MVC5 project

Comment: Check what connection string you have after deployment. And, what build are you using for deployment(Debug/Release). See if the connection string differs for the builds.

Comment: Could it be that from the very begining you were using a local DB for authorization/autehntication? By default if you use `MembershipProvider` (which seems to be the case) it creates the tables that's using exactly on the local instance of SQL SERVER unless you specifically point to somewhere else?

Comment: @Shuhel I posted the published connection string.  It is different due to my different environment but I checked that removing the Authorize attribute but using teh same connection string works.

Comment: @Leron, There is a default MembershipProvider (SQL) and I did try specifying my connection parameters directly there but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: I'm writing this as comment becase Ive forgotten how actually I did this some time before but I remember that I mapped explicitly my MembershipProvoder with the tables from the SQL SERVER database whcih I think is part of your problem if you are trying just to pass a connection string but not mapping the tables which the MemebrshipProvider should use!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was a pretty common problem in MVC4 but the MVC5 solution is different.  Ultimately I solved it by finding the solution in this post: http://forums.asp.net/t/1952572.aspx?Problem+using+roles+with+MVC5 which involeved adding this line to the web.config modules section

```
<remove name="RoleManager" />
```